# Strange issue with jQuery .hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a site for a client but I've encountered a strange bug with jQuery's `.hide()` function

If you check out this [sample url](http://www.robotwp.com/clintenglish/) and click any one of the thumbnails you'll see the image is aligned to the left. Now if you open or switch to any other browser tab and then go back to the sample url the image is centered...

The image should be centered, and worked just fine until I added this;

```
$(".single-content-overlay").hide();
```

to my scripts file...

Anyone have any ideas why this might be happening and how I might be able to fix it?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: If you do it with dev console open and switch tabs, it won't happen. When it first loads, your `img` has `margin-left/right` set to 0, when you change tabs, `margin-left/right` gets set to `252px` because of an `auto` propery.

Comment: Side note, you have two minor HTML issues: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.robotwp.com%2Fclintenglish%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: It looks like the li with class 'slide flex-active-slide' element is width 0px when you first load it. Do you determine this programmatically based on the width of a parent?

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem with CSS (probably generated by your slideshow javascript lib). When the browser gets the focus again, the `<li>`s width are recaldulated. This:

```
<li class="slide flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
    <img alt="#" src="http://www.robotwp.com/clintenglish/wp-content/themes/clintenglish/images/samples/marley.jpg">
</li>
<li class="slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
    <img alt="#" src="http://www.robotwp.com/clintenglish/wp-content/themes/clintenglish/images/samples/marley.jpg">
</li>
```

Becomes this:

```
<li class="slide flex-active-slide" style="width: 1088px; float: left; display: block;">
    <img alt="#" src="http://www.robotwp.com/clintenglish/wp-content/themes/clintenglish/images/samples/marley.jpg">
</li>
<li class="slide" style="width: 1088px; float: left; display: block;">
    <img alt="#" src="http://www.robotwp.com/clintenglish/wp-content/themes/clintenglish/images/samples/marley.jpg">
</li>
```

The same behavior happens in Chrome, Firefox and IExplorer (all the latest versions). I'm  almost certain that this is a issue (or a feature?) with your slideshow lib. Try to define the `<li>`s width manually to see if the problem continues.

Comment: Defining the width manually solves the problem, but the site needs to be responsive so fixed widths aren't exactly ideal...